# Check if Windows user exists in SQL Server using Powershell. Remove Sa rights if so

Tags: sql, powershell

I'm looking to check if a user exists in SQL Server using PowerShell and remove their sa rights if they do. So far I have

```
clear
sqlps
cd "sql\$env:COMPUTERNAME\default"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query {if exists (select name from sys.database_principals where name='Builtin\Administrators') ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] DROP MEMBER [Builtin\Administrators]
else 
print 'Account Does not exist or SA has already been removed from account' }  #Runs a query on SQL Server to remove the SA privilege from Builtin\Administrators
exit
```

For some reason it chokes when I try to run this. It complains of the following error:

```
Missing '(' after 'if' in if statement.
At line:4 char:26

Missing closing ')' after expression in 'if' statement.
At line:5 char:1

Missing statement block after if ( condition ).
At line:5 char:1

Missing statement block after 'else' keyword.
At line:6 char:1
```

Passing the whole query as a string with single quotes

```
clear
sqlps
cd "sql\$env:COMPUTERNAME\default"
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query 'if exists (select name from sys.database_principals where name='Builtin\Administrators') ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] DROP MEMBER [Builtin\Administrators]
else
print 'Account Does not exist or SA has already been removed from account';' #Runs a query on SQL Server to remove the SA privilege from Builtin\Administrators
exit
```

gives me a different error at least.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'Builtin\Administrators) ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] DROP MEMBER [Builtin\Administrators]
else
print Account'.
At line:4 char:14
+ Invoke-Sqlcmd <<<<  -Query 'if exists (select name from sys.database_principals where name='Builtin\Administrators') ALTER SERVER ROLE [sysadmin] DROP MEMBER [Builtin\Administrators]
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Comment: Slightly edited the code. I found the SQL code to do it, but it chokes in sort of the same way.

Comment: When you ask for help and you mention an error, do try to actually post said error. The exact error message.

Comment: Added errors to question

Comment: This is officially driving me insane. Nothing I'm doing to this is working. Even when I can get it to work by removing the if statement, it requires a user to manually hit "Enter" on the PowerShell script screen.

Comment: You don't know the syntax of writing a PowerShell scripts. Learn first the basics, eg. 
[Windows PowerShell: Scripting Crash Course](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh551144.aspx). Once you know how to write a script that is syntactically correct, you can ask specifics of how to do the job you want it to do.

Comment: I know the syntax of regular PowerShell commands, though admittedly I am fairly new to using SQL with it. When I hit enter after copying the command it returns a double carrot. I then have to hit enter twice and does what I need it to do, but I don't know why there is a double carrot that comes up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -Query parameter for invoke-sqlcmd is a string.  You passed a scriptblock.

That should get you moving in the right direction.

Also, @Remus is right...including the error message will get you better help.

Edit:  Now that you're using a string parameter, you should probably use double-quotes around the query since you have single quotes embedded in it.

Comment: Edited top comment with new error that attempting to pass as a string gives me